# JVM opening another JVM using a different file.enconding

Tags: java, jvm

If a start my application using the parameter file.enconding and then my JVM creates another JVM file.enconding parameter will not be inherited be the second JVM. The second JVM will use the system enconding.

Can I set the JVM to open another JVM with the same file.enconding ?

Comment: Just a note: Instead of relying on `file.encoding`, it's better (more robust) to explicitly specify the encoding whenever you perform I/O. Of course, you may still need `file.encoding` for code you cannot change...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `-Dfile.encoding=YOURENCODING` as a command line argument to the second JVM.